# Kernel of Hankel Transform

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, special-functions, integral-transforms

I need to solve a cylindrical diffusion problem that is defined in $[1,\infty]$. I would like to use Hankel Transform that has is defined on $[0,\infty]$. So in order to apply Hankel transform in my case, do I need to change the Kernel of the Transformation.

Comment: You probably have a condition at $r=1$. So your transform should be tailored to that condition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do.

In general, the Bessel solutions to the boundary value problem require that the function remains finite at r = 0.

If your domain does not include r = 0 (and yours does not!) then you need to use a linear combination of Bessel functions of the first, and second kind.

A bit of Googling will help you to get a good idea about how to go about this. For example, "Theory and Operational Rules for the Discrete Hankel Transform" is a very nice paper which attempts to put the DHT on equal footing with the discrete Fourier transform.